# Accessing mock bluetooth GPS coordinates in cordova geolocation

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, gps

I have a cordova application that uses the geolocation plugin. I'm trying to use an external bluetooth antenna (Garmin GLO) to have a more precise geolocation.
The code in itself is relatively simple (for instance identical to http://terokarvinen.com/2015/gps-geolocation-in-cordova-and-android for all intent and purposes) using :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,[geolocationError],[geolocationOptions]);
```

With other applications, to use the bluetooth GPS, I simply have to connect to the Bluetooth GPS using Bluetooth GPS app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=googoo.android.btgps&hl=fr) which has a Mock Provider to "replace" the internal GPS. Beforehand, I of course pair the GPS, enable mock location in the development settings, etc. The geolocation data of the bluetooth GPS is then used instead of the internal GPS through the mock provider.

However, when I try to do the same with my cordova application, the mock location isn't used and no location is received (time out error). Permissions used are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

I have used cordova-plugin-mock-location  to test mock location is enabled in my app, and it is. I have tried cordova-plugin-advanced-geolocation instead of the other one, but the same problem occurs (no return from mock provider).

How can I use the receiver in my app using the Mock GPS Provider?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else comes across a similar problem, I was finally able to make it work using the GPSLocation plugin (https://github.com/louisbl/cordova-plugin-gpslocation), which uses native code instead of HTML5, instead of the Geolocation plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation).

For some reason, the base geolocation plugin seems to "freeze" the position requests when the mock GPS location is active : when the mock is disactivated, the multiple geolocation requests made during the mock only then seem to be sent and the onSuccess received.

Hope this helps!